# Topology tab looks connected but degisner tab is not connected in Oracle Data Integrator

Tags: oracle, repository, oracle-data-integrator

I am connecting to a repository in Oracle Data Integrator ODI (Standalone Edition Version 12.1.3).

I can see contents of topology and Operator tabs but while I am switching to Designer tab, it says:
`"Not Connected to a Development Work Repository".`

What should be the cause and how can I be able to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of Work Repositories :

- **Development** Work Repositories allow to create the data integration jobs by creating mappings, packages, procedures, user functions, variables and so on. It's Design-Time, so it gives access to the designer. From all that, we can create Scenarios, which are some executable blackboxes (you can see it as "compiled code"). A scenario can be done from a Mapping, a Procedure or even a whole package. We can then create Load Plans to sequence all these scenarios, define if we want to load it in parallel, define how to handle errors, ... Typically, Development work repositories are only used for the development environment(s) and a potential hotfix environment.
- **Execution** Work Repositories are only to execute Scenarios previously created in a Development Work Repositories. So they don't give access to the Designer. We have access to the topology to specify how to connect to your databases (typically Test, UAT, Pre-Production, Production). We also have access to the operator to import Scenarios and Load plans, execute them and see the result of the execution. We can even create new Load Plans there. An execution work repository is recommended to every environment where code should not be modified.

If you want to see the code, you need to ask an access to the Dev environment.

Comment: By the way the Topology is stored in the Master repository, not in work repositories, so you always have access to it.

Comment: I've met the same problem, and don't know how to fix this problem. Sorry but in the answer, is not showed real solution for this kind of problem. Could someone please, help me with this question?

Comment: The solution for my case, was just in restarting the ODI itself.

Comment: You probably connected to a different repository after restarting it, one in development mode.